# Selenium and WhatsApp for sending a message to specific phone number

Tags: java, selenium, whatsapp

I have automated the `whatsapp web` with the `selenium`.

It is able to send messages to the list of phone numbers... No matter
even if the phone number is saved in phone contacts or not

How Can i avoid re-loading of the same URL again and again for every phone number...?

Java Code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("side")));

System.out.println("Scanned the Barcode and loaded the web WhatsApp....");


// SendToList is a list of phone numbers...


for (int i = 0; i < SendToList.size(); i++)
{
     String Number = SendToList.get(i);
     System.out.println("Opening link....");
     driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+Number);

     try
     {
          Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
          alert.accept();
          System.out.println("Leave Page Alert accepted....");
     }
     catch(NoAlertPresentException e)
     {
          System.out.println("Leave Page Alert not detected....");
     }

     System.out.println("Typing the message text here....");

}
```

Is there any way instead of re-loading the URL [https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+Number](https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%22%20Number) again & again, for sending message to every new phone number...? Like injecting javascript or anything else?